# How to make quarterly population data stationary?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, arima

So, I am trying to build the Time Series model for the quarterly population estimate for Ontario provided by Stats Canada (https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1710000901). As seen below, the data is not stationary even after log differencing since mean is not constant. Also, how can I deal with the non-constant variance in latest months.

- Differencing of 1 for logged Time Series

[image]

Interestingly, Dickey-Fuller test shows that the statistics are significant at 5% and 10% levels:

Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:

Test Statistic                 -3.212856

p-value                         0.019252

#Lags Used                      9.000000

Number of Observations Used    77.000000

Critical Value (1%)            -3.518281

Critical Value (5%)            -2.899878

Critical Value (10%)           -2.587223

dtype: float64

Thanks!

Comment: Differencing of Moving Average and Exponential Moving Average produce similar results.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said,  my pretty strong advice is don't try to hammer a square peg into a round hole; try, as much as you can, to work with the series as it is, instead of trying to reform in the image of what is said to be a desirable property. If the textbook models aren't actually an accurate representation of the real data, then stop looking at textbook models and look for something else. I know this is easier said than done. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. Have already posted the question on the stats stackexchange. Sooo, possible way to make data stationary is to: 1) take log of data, 2) subtract moving average from the logged data, 3) subtract difference from the difference using the lag of 1. This seems to stationarize the data somewhat.

Comment: I'd like to take this opportunity to ask you again to consider why it is important to make the data apparently-stationary and what you stand to gain from doing that. It's not important to me if you answer this question here and respond to me -- I'm hoping to get you to think about it for yourself.